rust docker build got error: "cannot find -lssl: No such file or directory" on Ubuntu Server
i have try build on Ubuntu Server GCP, it was not successfully thought i already install musl-dev,
here is my Dockerfile
FROM rust:alpine AS builder

# Set the current working directory inside the Docker image
WORKDIR /usr/src

# Copy the Cargo.toml file and your source code into the Docker image
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
COPY src ./src
COPY secrets ./secrets
# Copy the dev-config.toml file
COPY dev-config.toml .

# Install build dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libgcc libstdc++ openssl openssl-dev pkgconfig musl-dev pcc-libs-dev

# Build the application in release mode
RUN cargo build --release

# Start a new build stage with Alpine
FROM alpine:latest

# Install necessary libraries. libgcc and libstdc++, etc are needed for the Rust binary
RUN apk add --no-cache libgcc libstdc++ openssl pcc-libs-dev build-base  openssl-dev pkgconfig musl-dev

# Add a new user 'appuser'
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

# Copy the binary from the builder stage to the current stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/target/release/my-api /usr/local/bin

# Change to non-root privilege
USER appuser

# Set the command to run your application
CMD ["my-api"]


the error is like this
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

= note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.80.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin:/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.80.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/self-contained:/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.80.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin:/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.80.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.....
.....the rest

= note: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/13.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl: No such file or directory
1099.5           /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/13.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto: No such file or directory
1099.5           collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

my os Ubuntu is on server to build that docker
with version 24.04 LTS , 10 GB, and 2 GB RAM
is that something i need to install again on docker ? i have stuck for few days to build this docker into server,

I would guess you're missing openssl libs.

i already have it on RUN apk add @ewokx

Side note: you shouldn't need the *-dev packages in the final image, only in the builder image.

I had the same issue trying to build a rust app in docker on my m2 Mac.
I found this thread, and the user polarathene suggested importing openssl-libs-static as well and it worked for me.
Hope it works for you too.
These are my relevant apk imports:
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache openssl-libs-static


Had a similar issue. Adding the openssl-libs-static helped. In my case I also had to add pq-sys to my Cargo.toml, as this apparently (internally) tells the linker to look for the right things.
